# How do I include NULL counts when using COUNT() and GROUP BY since COUNT ignores NULLs in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, count, group-by, null

MySQL can't count NULL values, when using the so-called `COUNT` function.

For example, we have a simple table:

```
supplier_id   supplier_name state
1             IBM           CA
2             Microsoft   
3             NVIDIA
```

This query:

```
SELECT 
  state
, COUNT(state) 
FROM atable
GROUP BY state
;
```

will return

```
CA    1
```

How can I modify this to show me the true nature of the table, which is

```
CA    1
NULL  2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `count(*)` to count # of rows with nulls.

```
SELECT state, count(*) FROM atable GROUP BY state;
```

The difference between `count(*)` and `count(state)` is that former doesn't count null values. You may find details and examples in [the docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/counting-rows.html).

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong -- but the `COUNT` function technically is behaving differently depending on what argument it is evaluating. I've never seen something so mathematically scary before.

Comment: @MonicaHeddneck it will be really great, if that was the scariest thing we see in everyday programming ))) It is a well known contract/simplification and everyone seems to expect it.

Comment: <begin rant> This is why I feel that MySQL is a terrible first language to learn. It teaches bad habits and makes everyone ambivalent about contradictions. It also teaches you to Repeat Yourself by reinventing the wheel constantly, making imperative programming difficult, (cursors, anyone?), and making you think it's okay to get hacky (LIMIT 1 to get the most recent? Limiting results != getting the most recent).

Comment: In this case, it appears that a function operates differently depending on what you put into it. What's next? "Sum only works when you count even numbers, but with odd numbers, it returns ASCII art showing a purple giraffe'. Why not? If we all agree it's a contract, then we go about out merry business. <end rant!! :D  >

Comment: @MonicaHeddneck this behavior is not MySQL-specific. You may use Oracle, PostgreSQL or MSSQL and you'll find the same behavior. The `count` function and its variants `count(*), count(distinct ..), count(all ..), count(col)` are specified in the [SQL 92 standard](http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~shadow/sql/sql1992.txt). But I agree that MySQL is not the best tool for imperative programming :) Just use the declarative style and you'll feel better. But I would recommend PostgreSQL)

Comment: @MonicaHeddneck This is function overloading - in PostgreSQL, which is what I use, a function's signature depends on its name and the number and type of its arguments, so if any of those change then you have a different function and so it's reasonable to expect different behaviour. I'd imagine MySQL is similar.

Answer (score 2):

Use COALESCE:

```
SELECT ...., COUNT (COALESCE (state, 'unknown')) ....
```

Comment: Glad to be able to help!